# Laravel register form with 2 fields with same name saved to different tables

Tags: laravel, forms, registration, user-registration

I have a custom user registration form, it registers a new user and a new church team at the same time. So this saves data to 2 different tables, the user table and the team table.  This form includes an input field for the User's phone number as well as the church Team's phone number. The issue occurring is that the phone number entered into the second phone field is overriding the first and saving into both tables rather than having them both saved respectively.

This is the phone input field from the registration form, this is the first one, it receives the Users phone number. The second field, which receives the Church teams phone number is identical except for the language  which is @lang('global.teams.fields.phone')

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('phone') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
     <label for="phone" class="col-md-4 control-label">@lang('global.app_phone')</label>

       <div class="col-md-6">
           <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" >

           @if ($errors->has('phone'))
              <span class="help-block">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
              </span>
           @endif
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Controller Validator and create code:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name'                  => 'required|max:191',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|max:191|unique:users',
            'password'              => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'church_name'           => 'required|max:191',
            'address'               => 'required|max:191',
            'state'                 => 'required|max:191',
            'city'                  => 'required|max:191',
            'zip'                   => 'required|max:191',
            'phone'                 => 'required|max:191',
            'g-recaptcha-response'  => [new ReCaptcha],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $team = Team::create([
            'name' => $data['church_name'],
            'address'  => $data['address'],
            'city'  => $data['city'],
            'state' => $data['state'],
            'zip' => $data['zip'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],

        ]);


        $user = User::create([
            'name'     => $data['name'],
            'email'    => $data['email'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'team_id' => $team->id

        ]);

        $user->role()->attach(config('app_service.default_role_id'));

        return $user;
```

I would like to save the two different unique phone numbers into their respective tables, what needs to occur in this code to get that result?

Comment: you have to set different name into input tag to your user's phone and church team's phone.

Comment: I have tried different input id tag names, there must be additional modifications needed because I get no change in results just by having different input Id tag names.

Comment: yes, you have to handle all with the new name. I posted in answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('user_phone') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
     <label for="user_phone" class="col-md-4 control-label">@lang('global.app_user_phone')</label>

       <div class="col-md-6">
           <input id="user_phone" type="text" class="form-control" name="user_phone" value="{{ old('user_phone') }}" >

           @if ($errors->has('user_phone'))
              <span class="help-block">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('user_phone') }}</strong>
              </span>
           @endif
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('church_team_phone') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
     <label for="church_team_phone" class="col-md-4 control-label">@lang('global.app_church_team_phone')</label>

<div class="col-md-6">
           <input id="church_team_phone" type="text" class="form-control" name="church_team_phone" value="{{ old('church_team_phone') }}" >

           @if ($errors->has('church_team_phone'))
              <span class="help-block">
              <strong>{{ $errors->first('church_team_phone') }}</strong>
              </span>
           @endif
        </div>
</div>
```

and controller:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name'                  => 'required|max:191',
            'email'                 => 'required|email|max:191|unique:users',
            'password'              => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'church_name'           => 'required|max:191',
            'address'               => 'required|max:191',
            'state'                 => 'required|max:191',
            'city'                  => 'required|max:191',
            'zip'                   => 'required|max:191',
            'user_phone'            => 'required|max:191',
            'church_team_phone'     => 'required|max:191',
            'g-recaptcha-response'  => [new ReCaptcha],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $team = Team::create([
            'name' => $data['church_name'],
            'address'  => $data['address'],
            'city'  => $data['city'],
            'state' => $data['state'],
            'zip' => $data['zip'],
            'phone' => $data['church_team_phone'],

        ]);


        $user = User::create([
            'name'     => $data['name'],
            'email'    => $data['email'],
            'phone' => $data['user_phone'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'team_id' => $team->id

        ]);

        $user->role()->attach(config('app_service.default_role_id'));

        return $user;
```

Comment: Yes, this does it. Thanks! I had tried something similar to this (changing all the names to unique identifiers)  that didn't work for me and now looking at your code I see why my attempt failed. I had the Controller create backward, I was trying 'user_phone' =>$data['phone'] instead of 'phone' => $data['user_phone']. So I had it backward, funny how that works. Thanks for your time on this I really appreciate it.